# I am trying to send get or post requests in javascript loop but .click() is only processing once

Tags: javascript, php, html

Please excuse my ignorance on web coding. I am only doing this to automate a one time, yet monumental task. 
I am trying to download many pdfs from an online resource that has no built in function to do so. On a separate thread I learned that I am prohibited from adding the download attribute to an anchor because the code isn't in the same origin.
So the work around I've figured out in Chrome you can set pdfs to download instead of open. This would require me go to each pdf link. So I wrote some php to redirect to a given url, now I just need a way to loop through each url. I am able to get all the urls for the files and put them in an array or text file. I just can't figure out how to loop through each url and force chrome to download each time a new pdf is loaded.

I am open to any approach that gets this done.
The only result I've been getting is the last url in the array is triggered and all urls before are ignored.

I have tried submitting a form via javascript get or post requests to php that change the "location" header to the url passed.

I have tried window.location.replace(urls[index]);

I have read about "closure" problems with javascript but the solutions I've found don't solve this either.
Here is what I currently have:

Html/JavaScript Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form type="hidden" id="trigger" action="test.php" method="get"><br></form>
    <script>

        //create inputs
        document.getElementById("trigger").style.display = 'none';
        var dummy_input = document.createElement('input');
        dummy_input.name = 'url';
        dummy_input.type = 'text';

        var dummy_input2 = document.createElement('input');
        dummy_input2.type = 'submit';

        //append to form element
        trigger.appendChild(dummy_input);
        trigger.appendChild(dummy_input2);

        var urls = [
        "https://some_url.com/1",
        "https://some_url.com/2"
        ];
        for(var i = 0;i < urls.length; i++){
            (function(){
                var ii = i;
                setTimeout(function(){  
                dummy_input.value = urls[ii];
                dummy_input2.click(); 
                },500);
            })();
        }       
    </script>
</body>
```

Php Code:

```
<?php
$url = $_GET["url"];
ob_start();
    while (ob_get_status()) { ob_end_clean(); }
    header( "Location: $url" );
?>
```

The end result should be that each url in my array or from a txt/csv file is navigated to, causing chrome to download the file, and the move onto the next url and so on.
Any approach I've tried results in only the LAST url being triggered. (Once again I'm sorry for my lack of know how here...But I have been researching for many hours before I came here.) Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why are you wrapping the code in your loop inside an IIFE?

Comment: It was a solution referenced in another article. I'm trying to trigger dummy_input2.click() for each value in my array of urls.

Comment: This looks like a job for _wget_, or maybe PHP and cURL. Can you run. PHP on your computer? Oh, and is what you propose within the terms of service of the site? If not, what you're trying to do could be illegal.

Comment: No, its legal. I have access to the resources already. We are migrating to another platform and I need to download all the documents... there just isn't any way for me to batch download.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `i` to the closure

```js
var urls = [
  "https://some_url.com/1",
  "https://some_url.com/2"
];
for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    var ii = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i)
      dummy_input.value = urls[i];
      dummy_input2.click();
    }, 500);
  })(i); // i added here
}
```

Alternatively you can use `let` instead of `var`:

```js
var urls = [
  "https://some_url.com/1",
  "https://some_url.com/2"
];
for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i)
    dummy_input.value = urls[i];
    dummy_input2.click();
  }, 500);

}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, Nice and simple solution

Comment: Hmm..I get a 404 error. Tried several including exactly the above.

Comment: So I think my browser was caching the old page and I got past the 404 error. However, I’m still getting the same behavior of click() only being triggered once and with the last array index.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution to download all files in one go.

```
for(var i = 0;i < urls.length; i++)
    downloadURI(urls[i]);

function downloadURI(url) {

    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    link.href = url;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
}
```